# Python Etiquette: Importing Modules

Tags: python, coding-style

Say I have two Python modules:

`module1.py`:

```
import module2
def myFunct(): print "called from module1"
```

`module2.py`:

```
def myFunct(): print "called from module2"
def someFunct(): print "also called from module2"
```

If I import `module1`, is it better etiquette to re-import `module2`, or just refer to it as `module1.module2`?

For example (`someotherfile.py`):

```
import module1
module1.myFunct() # prints "called from module1"
module1.module2.myFunct() # prints "called from module2"
```

I can also do this: `module2 = module1.module2`. Now, I can directly call `module2.myFunct()`.

However, I can change `module1.py` to:

```
from module2 import *
def myFunct(): print "called from module1"
```

Now, in `someotherfile.py`, I can do this:

```
import module1
module1.myFunct() # prints "called from module1"; overrides module2
module1.someFunct() # prints "also called from module2"
```

Also, by importing `*`, help('module1') shows all of the functions from `module2`.

On the other hand, (assuming `module1.py` uses `import module2`), I can do:
`someotherfile.py`:

```
 import module1, module2
 module1.myFunct() # prints "called from module1"
 module2.myFunct() # prints "called from module2"
```

Again, which is better etiquette and practice? To import `module2` again, or to just refer to `module1`'s importation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `import module2`. Re-importing is relatively costless, since Python caches module objects in [sys.modules](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules).

Moreover, chaining dots as in `module1.module2.myFunct` is a violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Perhaps some day you will want to replace `module1` with some other module `module1a` which does not import `module2`. By using `import module2`, you will avoid having to rewrite all occurrences of `module1.module2.myFunct`.

`from module2 import *` is generally a bad practice since it makes it hard to trace where variables come from. And mixing module namespaces can create variable-name conflicts. For example, `from numpy import *` is a definite no-no, since doing so would override Python's builtin `sum`, `min`, `max`, `any`, `all`, `abs` and `round`.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the [PEP 8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> When importing a class from a class-containing module, it's usually okay to spell this:
>
> ```
> from myclass import MyClass
> from foo.bar.yourclass import YourClass
> ```
>
> *If this spelling causes local name clashes*, then spell them
>
> ```
> import myclass
> import foo.bar.yourclass
> ```

Emphasis mine.

Don't use `module1.module2`; you are relying on the internal implementation details of `module1`, which may later change what imports it is using. You can import `module2` directly, so do so unless otherwise documented by the module author.

You can use the [`__all__` convention](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) to limit what is imported from a module with `from modulename import *`; the `help()` command honours that list as well. Listing the names you explicitly export in `__all__` helps clean up the `help()` text presentation:

> The *public names* defined by a module are determined by checking the module’s namespace for a variable named `__all__`; if defined, it must be a sequence of strings which are names defined or imported by that module. The names given in `__all__` are all considered public and are required to exist. If `__all__` is not defined, the set of public names includes all names found in the module’s namespace which do not begin with an underscore character (`'_'`). `__all__` should contain the entire public API. It is intended to avoid accidentally exporting items that are not part of the API (such as library modules which were imported and used within the module).